# How to find an equation of the function $f$ which has a specific tangent line to that function's graph, at a specific point?

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives, graphing-functions, tangent-line

E.g. how to find an equation of the function $f$ which has a specific tangent line to that function's graph e.g.: the equation of the tangent line to the function $f$ could be $y=\frac{1}{2}−\frac{3x}{2}$; and there's a point which lies both on the $f$'s graph and the graph of that tangent line, i.e.:
$\exists (1,−1) \in y \wedge \exists (1, -1) \in f$ | $y$ is a tangent line to non-linear $f$ at $(1, -1)$ where $y=\frac{1}{2}−\frac{3x}{2}$. How to find the equation of $f$?

Another example would look like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEjcy.png)
We're looking for the equation of the purple function; the red line is the purple's function tangent line and the point at which they meet is the specific point.

Comment: There are infinitely many functions with that property. Do you want it to specifically be a quadratic one?

Comment: @eyeballfrog that's the example that came to my mind just to explain what I mean. I'm looking for a general solution plus maybe the solution to this specific example if that's not a problem but I reckon I should be fine coming up with the solution from the general concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line with slope $m$ that passes through point $(h,k)$ will be tangent to any function of the form
$$
f(x) = k + m(x-h) + (x-h)^2 g(x).
$$
If you're given the line in the form $y = b + mx$ and want $f$ to be tangent at $x = h$, this can be written equivalently as
$$
f(x) = b + m x + (x-h)^2 g(x).
$$
This works because $(x-h)^2 g(x)$ is always zero and has zero derivative at $x = h$, so $f(x)$ will have the same value and slope as the line there. So for the line $y = 1/2-3/2 x$, a function tangent at $x = 1$ will have the form
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2} x + (x-1)^2 g(x)
$$
for some function $g(x)$.

Note that $g(x)$ can be *any* function that doesn't blow up at $x = h$. There might be other restrictions, but they're technicalities it's probably not worth getting into.

Comment: so in my example it'd be 
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{2}−\frac{3x}{2};
k = \frac{3}{2};
h = -1;
k = 1
$$
? I did try it an it works for $m, h, k = 1$ but not for any point so I must be understanding something wrong. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hwv9jomw6i 
great effort thanks for this!

Comment: @carrotcake Updated the explanation a little. Is it more clear now?

Comment: it does look clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A tangent line is a straight line which has degree 1.

A tangent line to another straight line is not possible. It is only a parallel line with minimum intersection.

For a second or higher degree curve say $y= ax^2+bx+c$:

In order to find the equation of tangent you have to equate its derivative to the slope of the given equation

$$2ax+b= \frac{-3}{2}$$

so that there are two coinciding points of intersection.